# Customize InfoWindow for a Fusion Table with drop down menu layers

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I've created a FusionTables layered map where I swap out the tableId and thus the visible map markers based on a selection from a drop down menu. I'm having trouble customizing the infoWindow properties for each layer once you've made your selection. After looking through several reference pages and tutorials, I've attempted to stylize the infoWindow and I've also unsuccessfully tried to implement the infoBox option as well. (I have stylized the infoWindow within the FusionTables workspace, but these styles do not import.) I have attached my code thus far; does anyone have any suggestions what I might try to a.) customize the window contents (select which FusionTable columns and subsequent data are on display within the window, and b.) stylize the window itself?

Any help is appreciated – Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Layered Map</title>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"

rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

#map-canvas { width:1250px; height:600px; }

.layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };

</style>



<script type="text/javascript"src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

</script>

<script src="/path/to/infobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;

function initialize() {

    var tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ';

    var locationColumn = 'Lat/Long';



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 265),

        zoom: 4,


        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      },

  });



    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

        query: {

        select: locationColumn,

        from: tableId

  }

});



    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('option'),

        'change', function() {

         updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn);

});

}



function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {

var option = document.getElementById('option').value;

if (option) {

switch(option){

  case "2": tableId = '1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w';

            break;

  case "3": tableId = '1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0';

            break;

  default:

  case "1": tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ'; // first tableId

            break;

}

layer.setOptions({

      query: {

         select: locationColumn,

         from: tableId,

       },

       map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2,

  });

 } else {

layer.setMap(null);

 }

}





 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);







</script>



</head>

<body>



<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<label>Layer:</label>

<select id="option">

<option selected>--Select--</option>

<option value="1">1</option>

<option value="2">2</option>

<option value="3">3</option>

 </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To get the FusionTable to use the formatted infowindows, you need to pass the [appropriate templateId and styleId into the FusionTable constuctor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206272/google-fusion-map-info-window-not-formatted)

Comment: [Example of 3 FusionTableLayers on a map, sharing a single infowindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/www_satpacktravel_com_api_v5b.html)

Comment: Awesome, I've edited my code and added ",
   styleId: 2,
   templateId: 2,"
And now it's adding styles for the first two layers as requested, but not the third layer?

Comment: Maybe that is using a different temlateId or styleId?

Comment: Makes sense. I don't know how to declare them inividually?

Comment: makes the code to change tables a tad more complicated you have to change the options as well as the tableId.  Do you know what the appropriate values are for all the tables?

Comment: ah, ok, yes, Option/Layer1 = styleId: 2, Option/Layer2 = styleId: 2, Option/Layer3 = styleId: 3. The tableId for each is listed in the example code also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add styleId and templateId the the function to change tables, and fix the appropriate one:

```
switch(option){
  case "2": tableId = '1io74LWVjfOc_MDtoMlnPc3EiLg_uYYrdImQs43w';
            var templateId =2;
            var styleId =2;
            break;
  case "3": tableId = '1LbTKT2JJ86I9smoa7Xrryo7mRLeC78Tiop9j7x0';
            var templateId =2;
            var styleId =3;
            break;
  default:
  case "1": tableId = '1JEUbXBVguPhTwEPncLV0GkF49Tp3ImCooKGGADQ'; // first tableId
            var templateId =2;
            var styleId =2;
            break;
}

layer.setOptions({
      query: {
         select: locationColumn,
         from: tableId,
       },
       map: map,
        styleId: styleId,
        templateId: templateId,
});
```